js file is not loaded, css file works in spring boot application
I have file index.html that looks like this:
<head>
...
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/index.css}"/>
<script th:src="@{/js/app.js}" type="script" async></script>
...
</head>

which is rendered like:
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/index.css">
<script src="/js/app.js" type="script" async="">

and file structure like this:

when visiting /index in browser, styles work but javascript is not loaded.
I have tried different filenames, accessing /css/index.css and /js/app.js in browser (works), adding following code (didn't change behavior):
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**", "/js/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/css/", "classpath:/static/js/");
}

Also, in browser network tab, I see that web page is loading index.css, but not app.js.

so, the type should be
type="text/javascript" 

what got me confused was this mozilla developer page for X-Content-Type-Options
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options?utm_source=mozilla&utm_medium=firefox-console-errors&utm_campaign=default
where i misunderstood following section (it got rid of previous error message, but left me with problem in this question)

nosniff


Blocks a request if the request destination is of type style
and the MIME type is not text/css, or of type script and the MIME type
is not a JavaScript MIME type.

